# Registering new users with different usernames and emails

Tags: php, if-statement, registration

I'm having a problem in my registration page. You can register a new user with a username already registered by using a different email.

For example, first registration:

**Username: User-1**
Password: 123
**Email: 123@email.com**

Message received: **"You are Registered"**

Another registration:

**Username: User-1**
Password: 123
**Email: another_email@email.com**

Message received: **"You are Registered"**

The page should be displaying **"Username already exists"** but that is not happenning. I really don't know what is missing.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1){
        ?><p><?php echo "Username already exists"; ?></p><?php
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 1){
        ?><p><?php echo "Email already exists"; ?></p><?php
    }
    else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
        ?><p><?php echo "You are Registered"; ?></p><?php
    }
}
else{

    if(empty($username)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a username";
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a password";
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a email";
    }
    foreach ($error as $value) {
        ?><p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p><?php
    }
}
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the help guys but i found a better solution for the problem. I'm using **$value** also to display **"Username already exists"** and **"Email already exists"** and also changed **mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1** to **mysql_num_rows($checkusername) > 0** as some of you suggested. Here is the new code:

```
<?php
include "header.php";

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){

    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
    $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 0 && mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 0){

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
        ?><p><?php echo "You are Registered"; ?></p><?php
    }
    else{
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) > 0){
            $error[] = "Username already exists";
        }
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) > 0){
            $error[] = "Email already exists";
        }
        foreach ($error as $value) {
            ?><p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p><?php
        }
    }
}
else{

    if(empty($username)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a username";
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a password";
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a email";
    }
    foreach ($error as $value) {
        ?><p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p><?php
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: A quick guess > 0 instead of == (or clear out your table). e.g. you already more than one user called Fred.

Comment: You are using deprecated and outdated mysql connectivity. Also, you are *very* vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, your `if` is wrong. If username matches, but e-mail doesn't the new user will still be created.

Comment: Why are you surprised by this? You check for duplicate usernames, but then don't do anything with that information. You just blindly insert the new record. Plus, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @Marc B, harsh, but true.

Comment: [RESOLVED]? WTF, this is not a support forum.

Comment: I just did that so people can see the solution but if you think is a bad idea i'll remove it.

Comment: People should be able to see the solution in the accepted answer. Although it seems like you accepted an answer that didn't really address the real problem in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `if` should be `elseif`.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1){
    ?><p><?php echo "Username already exists"; ?></p><?php
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 1){
    ?><p><?php echo "Email already exists"; ?></p><?php
}
else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
    ?><p><?php echo "You are Registered"; ?></p><?php
}
```

The way you wrote it, the `INSERT` is done whenever the email test fails, but the username test doesn't stop it.

You should also create unique keys for the username and email columns in your table, so that duplicates can't be created.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, if you have two User-1s already from previous testing ==1 would return false? Try >=1?

I'm not sure the || mysql_die() is a great idea either, but probably not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May you have more then one user with this username in your Database. May try something like this

```
mysql_num_rows($checkusername) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your `if` is wrong causing you to insert the user if the entered e-mail doesn't exist yet.

But also, the check is a bit risky. You check if the number of matches is *exactly* 1. That means that if, for whatever reason, the user already exists twice in the database, you can keep adding more users with the same name.

Finally, apart from fixing all this logic in the script, make sure to add a unique index to the username field and a similar one to the e-mail field. That way, it is technically impossible to create duplicate users, regardless of flaws in your script.

You will still need to fix the way you contact MySQL, though. How you do it now is outdated and very dangerous.